# How can I set Touch Target Expansion on TRectangle in Delphi FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, touch, firemonkey

I'm using `TRectangle`'s for buttons on an FMX app, unfortunately, there's no property setting for `TouchTargetExpansion` like there's in most styled-components.
What is the way to get it on basic components such as `TRectangle`?

Comment: You would have to create your own control. Look at the implementation in the source code of a control that has that feature, and come back with questions about details, if you get stuck. Or better, more simple, instead of a `TRectangle`, use a control that already has the feature, e.g `TButton`, `TCustomCornerButton` etc. .... Enter `TouchTargetExpansion` in the search box in help, and you will see a list of all controls that have the feature.

Comment: The reason I'm using `TRectangle`  over `TButton` i.e., is that I have more flexibility on the UI, which I don't have that easy with other controls. So I would appreciate having this implemented in `Trectangle`

Answer (score 0):

Another option that I used a lot is to add a TRectangle with fill color null over text and controls. Then you control the click area using this invisible rectangle. That way you can forget about the Touchtargetexpansion option and use this "invisible touch rectangle" on any area or component.